# Dystopian young adult novel about an orphan forced to live with a medical organization

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, dystopia

My friend is looking for a novel they read in 2018; they remember it having a one-word title.

The story is set in a post-apocalyptic future with a world fallout, tribes, maps, and futuristic elements. The protagonist is an orphan (likely female) who travels from place to place and is eventually swept up by a medical organization and forced to live with them, despite not wanting to. Eventually, they warm up to a girl with a scar on her esophagus, because someone literally took her voice.

Any help?

Comment: There is a book called [Davy by Edgar Pangborn](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/920957.Davy) that is along the lines you describe, but the protagonist is male and the book is from 1965.

Comment: my friend says this isn’t right but thanks!!